# Can I post a project to find a freelancer developer to do it?

Tags: support

I'm looking a developer to write a Woocommerce Plugin. 
Is there any place/way to post my project to find the right freelancer to do it?

Comment: Simple answer === No.

Answer (score 5):

Like Stack Overflow and all the other Stack Exchanges; this site handles Question/Answer formats in which one person asks a WordPress specific question and others volunteer answers. This is not the place to post project/job requests.

There are various freelance websites where you can post your project to that I'm sure you can find with a quick search.